# Debian Jessie - Random freezes

Tags: debian, freeze, random

I have a fresh installation of Debian Jessie, with Cinnamon and Gnome. I run it on a decent computer with the following specs:

```
Athlon II x3, 6GB DDR2, 2GB SWAP (swapiness minimum), 600GB SATA HDD (new), Nvidia G210 with latest drivers ...
```

I have all latest updates and Ubuntu works well, however, Debian freezes for about 30-120 seconds when I start some applications. I am able to move my mouse, but not able to click anything.

I have tried rebooting and re-installing `Debian` but the issue still persists.

It would appear that sometimes the computer runs slowly, but only on `Debian Jessie`. I am able to run Windows with only a few problems such as a `DPC latency` issue. However, a reboot fixes the problem.

I forgot to mention that `Debian Jessie` is unable to hibernate. It hangs on a black screen indicating there is no video signal. Only issuing a hard-shutdown works.

- journalctl -b0 -k → http://pastebin.com/WnBxGDtM
- dmesg → http://pastebin.com/ayVH7pV5

I captured this in `dmesg` 15 minutes before the error:

```
[45967.243270] perf interrupt took too long (2517 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
```

Comment: anything in `dmesg` (or `journalctl -b0 -k`) from around when its happening?

Comment: Just updated question with links to those logs. Thank you for your interest to help me out! Sublime took around 30 seconds to load one of logs... Too long...

Comment: I don't see anything in the kernel logs, unfortunately. Is it only the first time you start the app? Is it the same app(s)? Also, if its easy enough to reproduce, how about an `iostat -kx 5` running (in a terminal) while you start one of those apps and it takes forever. (You might have to install the `sysstat` package.)

Comment: No, it's always, happening with Archive Manager (opening/closing), mplayer/mplayer2 (starting), Chrome (uploading, downloading, minimizing), NetBeans (starting/closing/creating project). All text viewers, especially default ones, and few others. iostat -kx 5 - https://imgx.elite7hackers.net/vKJ7se1IG3o3s/2015/03/30/Screenshot_from_2015-03-31_012709WIAV9.png
<- Captured while reproducing the issue

Comment: Forgot to mention that while running  iostat -kx 5 freeze periods are a lot shorter. Weird.

Comment: Ok. You've got me scratching my head now. The system thinks its mostly idle, CPU-wise (%idle). And same with I/O (%util). How long were the freeze periods with it running? Still over 5 seconds (the refresh rate of that iostat)? [I'm tempted to say "try `iostat -kx 1` as a workaround"]

Comment: With it running freeze periods are between 5-10 sec, without more than minute. It's interesting :P Even with iostat -kx 1 it freezes for around 5-10 seconds.
Also, with some GTK software Segmentation fault error occurs. Eg. software-properties-gtk causes "Segmentation fault".

Comment: Hmm, segfaults suggest running memtest86/memtest86+

Comment: Okay, I will, but it's interesting that Ubuntu(great) and Windows (sometimes with DPC latency) are working fine.

Comment: Tested with memory86+ test passed without errors.

Comment: Somehow I missed that Ubuntu works. Are you using the same version of the nVidia drivers under both Ubuntu and Debian? Make sure you're not, e.g., using the open-source (nouveau) driver under Debian and the proprietary one under Ubuntu (or vice versa).

Comment: I don't use any on Ubuntu, it worked out-of-the-box. Debian runs one installed with apt-get, it have nvidia in it's name, I forgot full package name, I didn't used one from the nVidia website because of painfull compilation, it require specific kernel, etc.

Comment: Well, you're using one of those drivers on Ubuntu—it probably just installed it for you automatically. What does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` look like? How different is it under Ubuntu?

Comment: So, there is my /var/log/Xorg.0.log - http://pastebin.com/fVn4eLXG
I don't see much difference between those two. (Debian Ubuntu) There is more warnings/errors in Debian.

Comment: `[    25.140] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  340.65  Tue Dec  2 09:10:06 PST 2014` ... that's your NVIDIA version on Debian, I presume. Same one on Ubuntu? Basically, Ubuntu and Debian are *fairly* similar. So need to find where the difference is—surely that's what's causing the problem on Debian.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that except Cinnamon, I also have installed KDE Plasma, and I decided to give it a try.

And guess what? For now, my system is faster than ever, it simply flys and there is no random freezes at all. 
So obviously, problems is with Cinnamon and/or it's configuration and/or it's "cooperation" with Debian Jessie.

Thanks to [derobert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/977/deroberthttps://unix.stackexchange.com/users/977/derobert) for all  effort to help me out.
I appreciate that.

Comment: Debian Jessie freezing in Spain too, and this is plasma desktop installed in a brand new box. Three freezes in two days.

Comment: It's not much better for me neither. It is not feezing that much, but it's kinda too slow comparing with another distros running KDE Plasma.

Comment: I'm attributing that to nvidia now. I hope applying [https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers) will work.

Comment: linux-headers-amd64 is already the newest version.
nvidia-kernel-dkms is already the newest version.
They realy need to take care about their Linux drivers. It seems that's a place where bunny lies.